# If I want to determine a particle's momentum or position, do I get this information from the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, measurement-problem, observables

I am confused about how one measures the dynamical variables (eg position) of a particle. I thought the wave function $\Psi(x,t)$ was the probability amplitude and $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$ represents the probability of finding a particle at that a given location and time.

But this information only gives us probabilities about position. What if I wanted to measure momentum? Do I get this info from the wave function too?

Comment: Fourier transform it!

Comment: Yes. In the position representation, you can use the [momentum operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator#Definition_.28position_space.29).

Comment: simply just sandwich momentum operator with SE

Comment: What does it mean to be in a "position representation" or "momentum representation"?

Comment: @StanShunpike: The position representation is $\langle x|\psi\rangle=\psi(x)$. The momentum representation is $\langle p|\psi\rangle=\psi(p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An observable that has a definite value is an eigenvalue of the operator. If $A$ is a hermitian matrix of which $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate, we have
$$\tag{1}A|\psi,a\rangle=a|\psi,a\rangle$$
You asked about the *wave function*, not the *state vector*, though. We can still get all the information we need from the wave function $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$, but we need to find a differential operator that corresponds to $A$. To do this, Fourier transform to $a$ space from $x$ space and find the operator that fulfills (1).

Suppose however that $|\psi\rangle$ is *not* an eigenstate. Then there exists *no* $a$ *such that*
$$A|\psi\rangle=a|\psi\rangle$$
Instead, we have a *probability distribution function* 
$$P(a)=|\langle a|\psi\rangle|^2$$
where $|a\rangle$ *is* an eigenstate. This tells us the probability of our particle having $a$ between $a$ and $a+da$. To get $\psi(a)=\langle a|\psi\rangle$ is the trick then. We insert a full set of position eigenstates:
$$\langle a|\psi\rangle=\int \langle a|x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle dx=\int \langle a|x\rangle\psi(x)dx$$ 
What is $\langle a|x\rangle$? We use the fact that $|x\rangle$ is Dirac normalizable:
$$\int\frac{da}{2\pi}e^{ia(x-y)}=\delta(x-y)=\langle x|y\rangle=\int \langle x|a\rangle\langle a|y\rangle da$$
By inspection, we see
$$\langle a|y\rangle=\frac{e^{-iay}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
Thus
$$\psi(a)=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-iax}\psi(x)$$
Which is of course just the Fourier transform.

Comment: So, given an operator $A$, if an eigenstate exists, we write that eigenstate as $$A|\psi\rangle = a|\psi\rangle$$ by definition. Does an eigenstate always correspond to an observable? By "definite value", what do you mean?

Comment: We preferably write $$A|\psi,a\rangle=a|\psi,a\rangle$$ or something similar. What you have is fine too. The $a$ labels the eigenstate. An observable refers to the operator. If there is no definite value, we get a PDF. For example, a wave packet does not have a definite position value.

Comment: What does the $,a$ add? Like what's its purpose? Also, so in my book by Griffiths, he uses $$Q\left(x,-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)$$ to denote an observable. Is it common to write the stuff in parentheses? I take it $A$ is our operator but I don't usually see $$A\left(x,-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)$$. I usually use hats because it keeps me certain what is an operator and what isn't.

Comment: The $a$ lets us distinguish between a state $|\psi,a\rangle$ and a state $|\psi,a'\rangle$. I haven't read Griffiths' QM book, but I can hazard a guess as to what his notation means. $Q$ is the position operator. In the position basis it acts as $x$ and in the momentum basis it acts as $-i\hbar\partial_x$.

Comment: I bet you are right. I haven't seen him use it as a momentum operator. He just never explicitly called it the position operator when he introduced it.

Comment: @StanShunpike: Careful: $Q$ is not a momentum operator, but it can be used in the *momentum basis*.

Comment: You are right! I just learned this. I was so happy! I couldn't figure out where $e^{ipx}$ came from and thought it too trivial to ask. But I found http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35746/66165 and this guy explain how to shift bases. I still don't really understand what we mean by a position basis, but at least now I can move back and forth between position and momentum bases. What does it mean to have a position basis of position space?

Comment: @StanShunpike: You can think of the various bases as being analogous to coordinate systems in a sense. We can work a problem in Cartesian coordinates. But sometimes it might be more convenient to use polar coordinates. In QM we have a similar situation. We might want to use a position or momentum or even energy basis. Ballentine's book has a chapter for problems in the position basis and another chapter for problems in the momentum basis.

Comment: Hey champ, care to chime in here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1155285/197705 its a basic question but I'd like a more thorough answer than the one I got